# Run-time error "76": Path not found in VBA excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 75 excel sheet files and for E column for each one of them,  I have a munch of numbers that I wanted to calculate the max value and average value. I was trying the following VBA modules where it loops through every single files in the folder and returns the max and average values in a new sheet.

```vb
Sub GetLargestAndAverage()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim largestValue As Double
    Dim averageValue As Double
    Dim totalCount As Long
    
    ' Set the folder path where your Excel files are located
    filePath = "A:\SCHOOL\2023_SPRING\MME449\Actuator_testing\"
    
    ' Loop through all Excel files in the folder
    If Right(filePath, 1) <> "\" Then filePath = filePath & "\"
    filePath = filePath & "*.xlsx"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set folder = fs.GetFolder(filePath) #debugger says error is here#

    Set folderFiles = fs.GetFolder(folder).Files
    For Each file In folderFiles
        If LCase(Right(file.Name, 5)) = ".xlsx" Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
            
            ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
                largestValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("E3:E" & lastRow))
                averageValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws.Range("E3:E" & lastRow))
                totalCount = totalCount + 1
                
                ' Output the largest and average values to the sheet
                With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                    .Cells(totalCount, 1) = file.Name
                    .Cells(totalCount, 2) = ws.Name
                    .Cells(totalCount, 3) = largestValue
                    .Cells(totalCount, 4) = averageValue
                End With
            Next ws
            
            wb.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    Next file
    
    ' Format the output
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Value = "File Name"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Largest Value"
        .Range("D1").Value = "Average Value"
        .Range("A1:D1").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

It says in `Set folder = fs.GetFolder(filePath)` line path cannot be found. I set the `filePath` variable exact the same as the location shown in file properties.

Its my first time trying to use this and got confused on the path.

I tried use `Set folder = fs.GetFolder(filePath).ParentFolder` but still the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
filePath = "A:\SCHOOL\2023_SPRING\MME449\Actuator_testing\"
'...
filePath = filePath & "*.xlsx"  '<< remove this!
```

then call

```
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(filePath) #debugger says error is here#
```

You're not passing in a *folder Path* but more like the kind of path with a wildcard you'd supply to `Dir()`

Something more like this should work:

```vb
filePath = "A:\SCHOOL\2023_SPRING\MME449\Actuator_testing\"
If Right(filePath, 1) <> "\" Then filePath = filePath & "\"

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each file In fs.GetFolder(filePath).Files
    If LCase(file.Name) Like "*.xlsx" Then
  
    'etc etc
```